# Set a variable to value if value is truthy

Tags: javascript, syntax, simplify

Is there a shorthand version of the following:

```
let myVar = "I contain a value!";

const myNewerVar = "I contain a newer value!";
if (myNewerVar) { 
    myVar = myNewerVar;
}
```

`myVar` should only be set if `myNewerVar` is truthy.

A shorter version of this is:

```
let myVar = "I contain a value!";

const myNewerVar = "I contain a newer value!";
if (myNewerVar) myVar = myNewerVar;
```

I don't like the repeated reading of `myNewerVar`, though.

Is there a way to simplify this even more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
myVar = myNewerVar || myVar;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use OR operator

For Example

```
myVar = myNewerVar || myVar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing in Typescript, you may also use nullish coalescing. It returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined.

```
const foo = null;
const bar = false;

const fooTest1 = foo || 'Test 1';  // Output: "Test 1"
const fooTest2 = foo ?? 'Test 2';  // Output: "Test 2"

const barTest1 = bar || 'Test 3';  // Output: "Test 3"
const barTest2 = bar ?? 'Test 4';  // Output: false
```

Comment: Nullish coalescing operator is a part of Javascript, so using Typescript is not required. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing